# Preview Pane column limit/fix

Tags: column, list-view

I have a discussion board that uses the Preview Pane style view. The Title, Body, Subject, Attachments, and Modified By are my columns showing in this preview pane. Primary way of posting is through the incoming email. The problem lies when the body is a big HTML format or big picture. When you go to hover over one of the big bodied titles, the title column shrinks and the position of the titles move (vertically).

The only way we can get around it right now is change views for those types of posts. I would like to know how we can restrict the column width or make it static. I would like to keep the preview pane functionality.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 preview pane has a static subject column, and pushes the content in the other direction rather squeezing the subject column.